# Getting disk full errors, df says 3GB free

Tags: disk-usage

I have a 63GB SSD drive, and since upgrading to 23.04 I've gotten "out of disk space" errors a few times.
Has happened with Audacity, and Android Studio

Running df -h at the same time as the last warning gives this result. If 60GB of the 63 are in use, why is only 59M being listed as available?

| Filesystem | Size | Used | Avail | Use% | Mounted on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tmpfs | 1.6G | 2.6M | 1.6G | 1% | /run |
| /dev/sdb4 | 63G | 60G | 59M | 100% | / |
| tmpfs | 7.8G | 4.0K | 7.8G | 1% | /dev/shm |
| tmpfs | 5.0M | 8.0K | 5.0M | 1% | /run/lock |
| /dev/sdb1 | 496M | 71M | 426M | 15% | /boot/efi |
| tmpfs | 1.6G | 100K | 1.6G | 1% | /run/user/126 |
| tmpfs | 1.6G | 140K | 1.6G | 1% | /run/user/1000 |
| /home/me/.Private | 63G | 60G | 59M | 100% | /home/me |

Restarting usually resolves the warning, but that's not ideal, what could be causing this?

Might not be related, but I've noticed that if I delete a file in Files, the item is not removed from the view

Comment: Your last remark seems to be about a bug in Files. I've noticed it too. Pressing F5 displays the correct file list.

Comment: 5% reserved blocks equal to 3 GB, that's why.

Comment: Can the /run/ directories be removed safely?

Comment: No! Don't do that.

Comment: I agree with @mook765. (Used + Avail) / Size = 0.95 on my desktop systems, 0.92 on my server.